# Parsing a config file in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

Here's my config file (dansguardian-config):

```
banned-phrase duck

banned-site allaboutbirds.org
```

I want to write a bash script that will read this config file and create some other files for me. Here's what I have so far, it's mostly pseudo-code:

```
while read line
do
    # if line starts with "banned-phrase"
        # add rest of line to file bannedphraselist
    # fi

    # if line starts with "banned-site"
        # add rest of line to file bannedsitelist
    # fi
done < dansguardian-config
```

I'm not sure if I need to use grep, sed, awk, or what.

Hope that makes sense. I just really hate DansGuardian lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ cat config
banned-phrase duck frog bird
banned-phrase horse
banned-site allaboutbirds.org duckduckgoose.net
banned-site froggingbirds.gov

$ awk '$1=="banned-phrase"{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i >"bannedphraselist"}
       $1=="banned-site"{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $i >"bannedsitelist"}' config

$ cat bannedphraselist 
duck
frog
bird
horse

$ cat bannedsitelist 
allaboutbirds.org
duckduckgoose.net
froggingbirds.gov
```

**Explanation:**

In `awk` by default each line is separated into fields by whitespace and each field is handled by `$i` where `i` is the i<sup>th</sup> field *i.e.* the first field on each line is `$1`, the second field on each line is `$2` upto `$NF` where `NF` is the variable that contains the number of fields on the given line.

So the script is simple:

- Check the first field against our required strings `$1=="banned-phrase"`
- If the first field matched then loop over all the other fields `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)` and print each field `print $i` and redirect the output to the file `>"bannedphraselist"`.

Comment: This does exactly what I need, but the syntax is so confusing! I guess I need to brush up.

Comment: I have added a short explanation, hopefully it helps. You may want to have a read of this for a full introduction to awk http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf

Comment: +1! It opens two file handles only once, which is a gread advantage. It could be made shorter and more cryptic: `awk '/^banned-(phrase|site) /{gsub(/-/,"",$1);for(i=2;i<=NF;++i)print $i >$1"list"}'`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
sed -n 's/^banned-phrase *//p' dansguardian-config > bannedphraselist
sed -n 's/^banned-site *//p' dansguardian-config > bannedsitelist
```

Although that means reading the file twice. I doubt that the possible performance loss matters though.

Comment: +1. It's possible to do this in pure Bash, but there's a noticeable tradeoff between cleanness and safety. With Sed you can do it both safely and cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

You can read multiple variables at once; by default they're split on whitespace.

```
while read command target; do
  case "$command" in
    banned-phrase) echo "$target" >>bannedphraselist;;
    banned-site) echo "$target" >>bannedsitelist;;
    "") ;; # blank line
    *) echo >&2 "$0: unrecognized config directive '$command'";;
  esac
done < dansguardian-config
```

Just as an example.  A smarter implementation would read the list files first, make sure things weren't already banned, etc.

Comment: I like how readable this is (compared to awk, sed, etc.). Would it become much more complex if the config file had lines like this: `banned-phrase duck pheasant mallard`? And and could you print those on separate lines in the resulting file?

Comment: Nice solution. Minor comment: `echo text >> file` will `open`, `lseek`, `close` each time it is called. The number of such calls could be reduced a lot using `exec 3>>file` and `echo text >&3`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with all the solutions which uses `echo text >> file`? It can be checked with `strace` that in every such step the `file` is opened, then positioned to the end, then `text` is written and file is closed. So if there is 1000 times `echo text >> file` then there will be 1000 `open`, `lseek`, `write`, `close`. The number of `open`, `lseek` and `close` can be reduced a lot on the following way:

```
while read key val; do
  case $key in
  banned-phrase) echo $val>&2;;
  banned-site) echo $val;;
  esac
done >bannedsitelist 2>bannedphraselist <dansguardian-config
```

The stdout and stderr is redirected to files and kept open while the loop is alive. So the files are opened once and closed once. No need of lseek. Also the file caching is used more in this way as the unnecessary calls to `close` will not flush the buffers each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read name value
do
  if [ $name = banned-phrase ]
  then
    echo $value >> bannedphraselist
  elif [ $name = banned-site ]
  then
    echo $value >> bannedsitelist
  fi
done < dansguardian-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^banned-phrase/{print $2 >> "bannedphraselist"}
     $1 ~ /^banned-site/{print $2 >> "bannedsitelist"}' dansguardian-config
```

Comment: Regular expression match isn't needed, neither is append and this only works for one value per line.

Comment: @sudo_O: This answer is based on this requirement from question: `if line starts with "banned-phrase"` Also I didn't see any requirement of having more than 1 phrases per line.

Comment: ... that doesn't mean you have to use regular expressions this of course can be done with a string comparison on the first field.

Comment: @sudo_O: What if `$1` is `banned-phrase123`?

Comment: Then your solution would mistakenly parse that line and append the second field to one of the files.

Comment: Not mistakenly, that's the intent behind putting this regex check. That is what it should happen as per OP's comment `if line starts with "banned-phrase"` (don't know the real intentions)